# PHP Array para formato arvore

Tags: php, array, treeview

Estou tentando transformar essa array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [enc] => Array
                (
                  [enc_obs] => Continua
                )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [per] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [per_obs] => Continuar mesmo?
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [enc_obs] => Continua2
                            [per] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [enc_obs] => Continua3
                                            [per] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [per_obs] => Finaliza1
                                                        )

                                                    [1] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [per_obs] => broker9
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Em algo algo parecido com isto

```
children: [
            {
                text: { name: "Account" },
                stackChildren: true,
                connectors: {
                    style: {
                        'stroke': '#8080FF',
                        'arrow-end': 'block-wide-long'
                    }
                },
                children: [
                    {
                        text: {name: "Continua"},
                        HTMLclass: "reception"
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                text: { name: "Continuar mesmo?" },
                children: [ 
                   {

                    children: [
                            {
                                text: {name: "Continua3"}
                            },
                            {
                                children: [
                                    {
                                        text: {name: "Finaliza1"}
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                text: {name: "broker9"}
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

Esse código acima com dados children irão gerar um gráfico parecido com isso

[image: Dados do Grafico]

Já tentei utilizar diversos métodos de array para tree etc.. mas não deu certo. O que tem me dificultado na programação é quando tenho a necessidade de fechar com o **]** e separar o children com **},**

Esse código que estou querendo gerar é baseado  [Treant.js](http://fperucic.github.io/treant-js/)

Comment: Acho que a confusão está no entendimento da diferença entre [ e { (vou tomar por base Object Notation que é usado no JSON). `[ ]` é para separar **valores individuais**: `[ 1, 'Claudio', 88, { "a":2 }, 98]` e `{ }` é para separar **pares** de **chave e valor**: `{ "id":1, nome:"Claudio", "doc":88, "flags":{ "a":2 }, "next":98 }`

Comment: Quanto à sua pergunta, seria bom [edit] e colocar um exemplo da array e da "árvore" (que na verdade seria um objeto) com os mesmos dados. Pra constar, O PHP já tem a [função `json_encode( )`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php) para fazer isso.

Comment: Ola Bacco, eu inseri os exemplos acima.. um é a array e a outra é a estrutura que eu estou desejando. Essa estrutura não é json.. é uma estrurua completamente diferente que gera esse gráfico que eu também citei.

Comment: O exemplo posto acima usa exatamente a notação do JSON, com as regras que eu comentei. Independente de estar usando no contexto de JSON, a sintaxe do que você postou é exatamente o que eu disse: pares separados com `{` e listas simples com `[`. Quanto à distribuição de valores, repito: melhor [edit] e colocar a mesma coleção de dados antes e depois, pois usar conjuntos completamente diferentes não ajuda muito a perceber detalhes fundamentais da conversão que você deseja.

Comment: Editei lá para que você possa compreender melhor... a dificuldade é que esta array é dinâmica e eu terei que gerar esses dados a partir da array mãe.

Comment: Continuam 2 coisas que não guardam relação. O que eu quis dizer é que os valores do seu array de exemplo deveriam ser os mesmos da "árvore" de saída. Você pegou um exemplo de array com dados completamente diferentes da saída que deu no exemplo. Só sugeri usar um exemplo realista para evitar ambiguidades para outros leitores e aumentar a chance de você obter o que procura.

Comment: Se tiver a curiosidade, veja o resultado do json_encode gerando a árvore do seu segundo exemplo, vindo de array: http://ideone.com/Kzmq0V

Comment: eu vi lá que tem toda a estrutura json mesmo... igualzinha.. acho que o que eu tenho que fazer é a partir da minha array mãe criar essa array para gerar o gráfico e depois transformar em json... mas deu uma boa luz já...

Comment: basicamente, quando você tem array( "nome1" => "valor1", "nome2"=>"valor2" )o encode vai gerar { }, e quando tiver array( "valor1", "valor2" ) o encode vai gerar [ ].

Comment: só que todas as keys com valor PER, 0 ou 1 terão que ser transformadas em children para funcionar

Comment: O resto vai depender da lógica dos seus dados originais. O `children` faz parte da especificação do Treant, seu código vai ter que adaptar os dados conforme o resultado que você quer.

Comment: o meu maior problema é realmente na parte da logica, para ler recursivamente a minha array e conseguir transformar ela no formato do Treant, já pensei em diversas formas e não consegui uma logica boa para sair disso... eu to perdido nisso.. acho que a minha pergunta acima é exatamente essa, como eu poderia ler a minha array e transformar ela em no Treant.. não to conseguindo...